Split is not recognized by Azure Devops Server 2022 - Yaml pipeline
We are using azure devops server 2022 and self hosted agents. When we try to run the pipeline
Version : Azure Devops Server 2022.0.1
we are getting the below error
Encountered errors while parsing YAML: /test.yml : unrecognized value: split.
Trigger: none
Pool:
   Name: testpool
variables:
- group: "DevInstanceList"
- name: InstancesList
  value: Instance1,Instance2

steps:
- ${{ each env in split(variables.InstancesList, ',')}}:
    - script: echo ${{ env }}


Hi @Learner, have you checked my latest update below? Did the split function of PowerShell work for you?

I can reproduce your issue when using Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1:

Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1 doesn't support string split function. This function is supported starting from Azure DevOps Server 2022 update 1.

If you want this function, upgrade to the higher version.

Update:
If you don't want to upgrade your server, you can use the default split function in PowerShell. For example:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $paths = "my-app/pom.xml my-newapp/pom.xml"
        
        # Split the string into an array of paths
        $pathsArray = $paths -split ' '
        
        # Iterate over each path and invoke Maven with 'clean verify'
        foreach ($path in $pathsArray) {
            mvn -f $path clean verify
        }


Hi @ Learner, do you have any question about this issue? If there is, feel free to let me know.

Nope. Thanks. So i cant use split function without upgrading the version. Am i right?

You can't use default YAML split function without upgrading the version. But you can use the default split function in PowerShell. If you want to use PowerShell's split function, you need to use maven command line in the PowerShell instead of Maven@3 task. See my update above. I have also shared this solution in your another question Pass array values as parameter to azure devops yaml template.
